# three.js change material for .obj file using a button

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm having trouble creating a button to change the .mtl file of my .obj to another .mtl using three.js. Any thoughts on how to do that would be awesome!

Here is the original code, adapted from the objmtl loader example on threejs.org. So far, I've only been able to make the obj visible / invisible using a button, but I'd love to add more buttons to change the .mtl files to reflect .mtls with other colors and properties.

```
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
                mtlLoader.setBaseUrl( 'examples/obj/male02/' );
                mtlLoader.setPath( 'examples/obj/male02/' );
                mtlLoader.load( 'male02_dds.mtl', function( materials ) {

                    materials.preload();

                    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                    objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
                    objLoader.setPath( 'examples/obj/male02/' );
                    objLoader.load( 'male02.obj', function ( object ) {


                        object.position.y = - 95;
                        dude = object;
                        scene.add( dude );

    info.innerHTML += '<br/><br/><input id=pants2 type="button" onclick="dude.visible = false" value="Dude: OFF"/>';
    info.innerHTML += '<input id=pants2 type="button" onclick="dude.visible = true" value="Dude: ON"/>';
```

Comment: maybe the first step would be splitting it into two functions, one to load the material, one to load the model?

Comment: Thanks, 2pha.. how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you can work without the .mtl file, you can use something like that:

```
texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('dir/to/texture.jpg');
sectexture =  new THREE.TextureLoader().load('dir/to/second_texture.jpg');
lambert = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xffffff, map: texture});
objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
objLoader.setPath( 'examples/obj/male02/' );
objLoader.load( 'male02.obj', function ( object ) {
    object.traverse(function(child) {
        if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh){
            child.material = lambert;
        }
    });
    scene.add( object );
}, onProgress, onError );
```

With that, you can load your texture into the lambert material, so if you want to change it you can use lambert.map=texture or lambert.map=sectexture.

[EDIT] I have fixed the mistake on child.material

Comment: Thanks a ton! Works well, except I had to change to child.material = lambert; .. Might you know of a similar process for swapping .obj files?

Comment: Oh, sorry for the mistake. If you want to swap between different .obj files the simplest solution that I can imagine is to try to make an global variable, and instead of scene.add(object) use something like that (if your variable is lala):
    lala = object;
    scene.add(lala);
after that, you can use scene.remove(lala) to remove your model from scene and after that again the scene.add(lala) if you want to add it again. With the same way you can add 2 or more obj models. Hope that will help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like I have to use mtls for my project. Might you know of a way to swap mtls for associated .objs using the original code I put above?

Comment: I think that there is a way to do that, but now I am very busy to try it. I have to check what type is that material and if is there any way to swap between mtls without reload the obj. If there are any other answer, I'l try to find a way to do that some days later.

Comment: Actually, I was able to use only .objs with using the method you originally described.